# -initWithReuseIdentifier: not called in ShinobiGrid cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, custom-controls, cell

I subclass a uitextfield into a customised cell to gain coordinates but it seems that the initWithReuseIdentifier is not being called and i got a null value in returned. i'm using shinobigrid cell for my table.

Hope anyone encountered this even though it is ShinobiGrid  :)

```
   #import "NumericCell.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation NumericCell
{
    UITextField *_txtNumberCell;
}
@synthesize cellNumber=_cellNumber;

-(id)initWithReuseIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier
{
    if (self =[super initWithReuseIdentifier:identifier]) {
        _txtNumberCell=[[UITextField alloc]init];
        _txtNumberCell.borderStyle=UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
        _txtNumberCell.textAlignment=UITextAlignmentRight;
        UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.7f];
        _txtNumberCell.font=font;

        [self addSubview:_txtNumberCell];
    }
    return self;

}
-(void)setCellNumber:(NSString *)cellNumber
{
    _cellNumber=cellNumber;

    _txtNumberCell.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cellNumber];
}

- (void)setFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    [super setFrame:frame];

    _txtNumberCell.frame=CGRectMake(50, 100, 10,  0);
    NSLog(@"text frame %f",_txtNumberCell.frame.origin.x);

}

#import <ShinobiGrids/ShinobiDataGrid.h>

@interface NumericCell : SDataGridCell
@property (nonatomic)NSString  *cellNumber;

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're setting up the grid and adding the columns, are you sure that you've set the celltype attribute?

It'd look like:

```
column.cellType = [NumericCell class];
```

Otherwise, can you please clarify where you're seeing the null value, and if any debugger triggers on any of the methods inside your custom cells?